# How can I prove that $(\mathbb Z,\leq_*)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb N,\leq )$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

We define the binary relation $\leq_*$ between integers by the following rule: For $n,m\in\mathbb Z$, $n\leq_∗m$ holds if and only if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

$|n|<|m|$, or

$|n|=|m|$ and $n<0\,$, or

$n=m$.

How can I prove that $(\mathbb Z,\leq_*)$is isomorphic to $(\mathbb N,\leq )$?

My thoughts:

I have to find a bijection $f : A_1 → A_2$. Then, I need to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism by showing that it is injective, surjective and that it preserves the order. However, I can't seem to find to find $f$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $0 \leq_* -1 \leq_*1 \leq_* -2 \leq_* 2 \leq_*\dots$

Comment: So I need a function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=-1$, $f(3)=2$, $f(4)=-2$... Right?

Comment: That would do the job, yes.

Comment: $f(n)=|n|+||n|-1|$. Is this valid?

Comment: This would not give you negative integers, or even $0$. Try to define $f(n)$ for even $n$, and then for odd $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I was defining f:ℤ→ℕ (it's also wrong). What about this: $f(2n) = -n$ and $f(2n+1)=n+1$  ?

Comment: Yes, that works. It should be straightforward to check that $f$ gives you the required isomorphism.

Comment: Aren't the elements ordered this way: $ 0≤∗-1≤∗1≤∗-2≤∗2≤∗…$?

Comment: Hmm I don't think $1≤∗−1$.

Comment: Ah, you are right. My mistake! I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13357/discussion-between-nick-and-user132349)